# How do you display a particular element on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a navigation bar that displays a particular element when hovered and clicked. I'd also like the other elements to remain hidden. I tried doing a few codes but it won't work even if I hovered it already.

```css
.yearly {
  display: none;
}

.evento {
  display: none;
}

.year a:hover+.yearly {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aacde2;
}

.event a:hover+.evento {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aacde2;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="listo">
  <ul>
    <li class="year"><a href="#">Yearly Donations</a></li>
    <li class="event"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="yearly">
    <img src="../images/pic1.jpg" alt="Photo" width="300px">
  </div>
  <div class="evento">
    <p>trial</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can read up about selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors In particular "The + combinator matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element."

Comment: If you have to keep that HTML structure then you will  need to use Javascript to sense when the mouse is over an anchor element and set the styling of the relevant content. Is JS acceptable and/or are you able to change the HTML structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Jquery.

```js
$(".year a").on({
  mouseover: function(e){
    $(".yearly").show();
  },
  mouseout: function(e) {
    $(".yearly").hide();
  }
});

$(".event a").on({
  mouseover: function(e){
    $(".evento").show();
  },
  mouseout: function(e) {
    $(".evento").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.yearly {
  display: none;
}

.evento {
  display: none;
}

.year a:hover + .yearly {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aacde2;
}

.event a:hover + .evento {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #aacde2;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listo">
    <ul>
      <li class="year"><a href="#">Yearly Donations</a></li>
      <li class="event"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="yearly">
        <img src="../images/pic1.jpg" alt="Photo" width="300px">
    </div>
    <div class="evento">
        <p>trial</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do they need to learn/load jquery rather than use pure Javascript?

Comment: any problems have alternative of solutions. I have utilize JQuery for the solution. so whats wrong in this?

Comment: Nothing implicitly wrong with jquery it just seems like a lot of code to have to load (and learn) for a small thing which could be done in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a Javascript function on hover. I'm sure there are better ways, but this works for example:

```js
function displayYearly() {
  document.getElementById("yearly").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideYearly() {
  document.getElementById("yearly").style.display = "none";;
}

function displayEvento() {
  document.getElementById("evento").style.display = "inline-block";
}

function hideEvento() {
  document.getElementById("evento").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#yearly {
  display: none;
}

#evento {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="listo">
  <ul>

    <li class="year" onmouseover="displayYearly()" onmouseout="hideYearly()">
      <a href="#">Yearly Donations</a>
    </li>

    <li class="event" onmouseover="displayEvento()" onmouseout="hideEvento()">
      <a href="#">Events</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div id="yearly">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="Photo" width="100px">
  </div>

  <div id="evento">
    <p>trial</p>
  </div>

</div>
```